# goodFeaturesToTrack error

Tags: c++, opencv

I've just started using OpenCV (2.4.13) with VS express 2013 and when I try to compile and debug this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    //cargar el archivo de video especificado
    VideoCapture vc("sequence.mpg");

    //verificar si se ha podio cargar el video
    if (!vc.isOpened())
        return -1;

    //obtener los cuadros por segundo
    double fps = vc.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    // calcular el tiempo de espera entre cada imagen a mostrar
    int delay = (int)1000 / fps;

    Mat frame1, frame2;

    bool bSuccess1 = vc.read(frame1);
    frame2 = frame1;

    vector<Point2f> features_prev, features_next;
    long int max_count = 50;
    double qlevel = 0.01;
    double minDist = 10;
    int blockSize = 3;
    bool useHarrisDetector = false;
    double k = 0.04;

    goodFeaturesToTrack(frame2, features_next, max_count, qlevel, minDist, Mat(), blockSize, useHarrisDetector, k);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error displayed on the console:

> `"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_BUC1 || src.type() == CV_32FC1) in cv::cornerEigenValsVecs, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\imgproc\src\corner.cpp, line 263"`

And VS express 2013 creates a window with the message:

> `"Excepción no controlada en 0x759796C2 en Ejemplo1.exe: excepción de Microsoft C++: cv::Exception en la ubicación de memoria 0x0117F014."`

Which I would translate as:

> `"Uncontroled exception at 0x759796C2 in Ejemplo1.exe: C++ Microsoft Exception cv::Exception at the memory address 0x0117F014."`

Any clue of what is happening here? What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you know that there's also a [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com/)? In the end, you can use which ever site you want, but now you know you have the choice.

Comment: I didn't know it! Thanks for the info and stopping here for leaving the comment. @Laurel

Answer (score 0):

**Typo** It is CV_8UC1 and not CV_BUC1. More info below.

Please note the important part in error message: `Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_32FC1)`

The CV_8UC1 or CV_32FC1 is actually CV_< NUMBER_OF_BITS_PER_CHANNEL>< U(Unsigned)/S(Signed)/F(float)>C< NUMBER_OF_CHANNEL>. Link to [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#storing-methods).

The message says that input image is of not proper type. You are probably reading the image from colored video and thus the type of frame is CV_8UC3, a colored image.

You should first create a grayscale image. Try [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) to create grayscale image.

Comment: On a side note, if you are new to opencv, use OpenCv 3.1. Much much better with new algorithms and redesigned for more readability and easy development.

Comment: Thank you for your support! It's already solved! @saurabheights

Comment: @JorgeChao In case if you faced a different issue, please add that as answer. For example, the biggest reason I have seen for opencv code crashing is due to linking Debug and Release libraries incorrectly. Keep improving the community.